# Normalization to control

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, normalization

Given two experimental runs, each with an experimental & a control group, I would like to test for a statistically significant difference between the first and second experimental group (using Welch's t-test). Because of inter-experimental variability, this requires **normalization of the values in the experimental groups** to their respective control group first.

The obvious (and often used) solution would be to divide each value in the experimental group by the mean of the corresponding control group (I have seen this described as "calculating the fold change" or "normalizing the data by setting the untreated control group as 1").

Is this a valid approach? What about the points made in http://biostat.app.vumc.org/wiki/pub/Main/TatsukiKoyama/RetreatPoster2009.pdf (Inflation of Type I error rates because of ignored variability in the control group mean; expressing effects as fold changes can hide true differences)?
I would greatly appreciate any comments or any resources with more details on this. Surely I can't be the first one struggling with this.

[I have posted a variation of this question [before](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67064/how-can-two-different-experiments-be-compared-when-they-have-different-controls), however, I don't think I have explained my problem very well then. I have spent quite some time researching this topic but was unable to find anything useful besides that poster.]